# Send notification at exact time and at every 24 hours

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

This is my code. I think this method is right but I am not able to show the notification at exact time. There is always a delay of a few minutes.

```
public void setSimpleAlarm() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 19);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 3, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're using `setInexactRepeating()`. As the name suggest and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)) confirms it's for a *"repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements"*.

The documentation for [`setRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)) contains the answer:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

Comment: Still getting notification after a few minutes.